# When accessing firestore, data always seems empty

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

hope you all are doing good. Whenever I am trying to access the database, the value is always empty. Here is my code:

```
 let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
 let usersRef = ref.child("Users")
 let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(userID!)
 thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
   let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
   let userType = value?["userType"] as? String ?? ""
   print("userType: " + userType)
   if (userType == "Volunteer") {
       self.volunteer = true
   }
 }
```

Whenever I print the value of userType, it should say volunteeer or In-need, but it is just an empty string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you use the [firebase] tag instead of [google-cloud-firestore]. Since this is a firebase real time database question, and not necessarily a firestore one, it may get you more views with someone who can help.

Comment: Sure, but do you know anybody who can help?

Comment: what does it read when you print(snapshot.value). I will try and help

Comment: @SanzioAngeli it just says nil when I print snapshot.value (or in my case, just value)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out using a different way.

Comment: Nice, sorry I could not help but glad you figured it out